# How to use multiple separate logger Serilog file in appsettings.json

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, serilog-sinks-file

I'm trying to configure Serilog two different files using **Serilog.Sinks.File** to store MVC project And another **Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer** my SQL server table. how can create two different places store error files?

Here is my **appsettings.json** file code

```js
"FileLog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "Logs/web-log-.log",
          "rollingInterval": "Day"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  
    "DatabaseLog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Warning",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "MSSqlServer",
        "Args": {
          "connectionString": "Server = DESKTOP-P9UP8PR\\SQLEXPRESS; Database = MVC_Project; User Id = MizanurRahman; Password = 682672;",
          "tableName": "Logs",
          "autoCreateSqlTable": true
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Database logging, but for multiple file logging appsettings.json file will be like this:

```
"Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Override": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Logger",
        "Args": {
          "configureLogger": {
            "Filter": [
              {
                "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
                "Args": {
                  "expression": "(@Level = 'Error' or @Level = 'Fatal' or @Level = 'Warning')"
                }
              }
            ],
            "WriteTo": [
              {
                "Name": "File",
                "Args": {
                  "path": "Logs/MyFirstLogFile.log",
                  "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:o} [{Level:u3}] ({SourceContext}) {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
                  "rollingInterval": "Day",
                  "retainedFileCountLimit": 7
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Logger",
        "Args": {
          "configureLogger": {
            "Filter": [
              {
                "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
                "Args": {
                  "expression": "(@Level = 'Information' or @Level = 'Debug')"
                }
              }
            ],
            "WriteTo": [
              {
                "Name": "File",
                "Args": {
                  "path": "Logs/MySecondLogFile.log",
                  "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:o} [{Level:u3}] ({SourceContext}) {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
                  "rollingInterval": "Day",
                  "retainedFileCountLimit": 7
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [
      "FromLogContext",
      "WithMachineName"
    ],
    "Properties": {
      "Application": "MyApplication"
    }
  }
```

Comment: They are BOTH called logger? How does it know which one to use?